# Wicket AutoCompleteTextField resizing modal window issue

Tags: wicket, dropdownchoice

I am using a AutoCompleteTextField from Wicket inside of a modal window. The problem is I have it near the bottom of the window, along with a dropdownChoice.

When I select the dropDownChoice, and if it is near the top, the drop down choice will drop down as normal, but if it is near the bottom of the window it will go up. For the AutoCompleteTextField if it's at the bottom, it will still drop down, and the modal window will become scrollable to view the choice. I do not want this, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still haven't found an answer to this, but for anyone who runs into this issue, the only simple solution I found to solve this is just to set a size limit on the div, and make it scrollable, like so:

```
  div.wicket-aa ul { list-style:none; padding: 2px; margin:0; max-height:55px;   overflow-y: auto; }
```